# Bitcoin Server accounts

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, json-rpc

I run Bitcoind and when I type account lists I get 4 accounts. Why?
How do I know which account is associated with bitcoin-qt? Also I never had any coins and using "move" command I moved 0.1 bitcoin to another account? How is this possible and how do I remove everything and start over?
Do I need to have bitcoin.conf written before I run Bitocind?

Answer (score 1):

You can and should ignore those accounts. The accounts mean nothing; they are just an internal thing in Bitcoin Core and will be removed soon. Accounts are done by the address labels, so when you change a label for an address, you are changing its account. But that really doesn't matter and you should not be using the accounts system at all.